# SQL - How can I query for all objects who have COUNT(0) of related objects in a reverse relationship?

Tags: sql, select, count

Here's what I have:

```
Person
    name = varchar

Helmet
    person = foreignkey -> Person
    is_safe = boolean
```

Now, for a batch job, I need to query (no ORM, just raw SQL) for all `Person` that have 0 `Helmet` that are safe. I could obviously just loop through each `Person` in the database, etc., but I need to do this in a single query and limit it to 100 at a time (there are novemdecillions of these suckers in the database), and remove each `Person`. I don't need the `Helmet` records for each to be attached in the result. I only need the `Person` records (naturally deleting will cascade), but I can't simply issue a `DELETE` in place of my `SELECT` because there are things I need to do elsewhere before deleting them.

I'm using Postgres, but I'd prefer to use a query that's more or less DB agnostic, if possible.

Here's what I've abstractly come up with:

```
SELECT * FROM person
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM helmet
        WHERE person_id = person.id AND is_safe = false) = 0
    LIMIT 100
```

This is clearly not valid SQL, but I'm hoping there is a functionally equivalent, but valid version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT h.person_id
        FROM helmet h
        WHERE h.person_id = p.id
            AND is_safe = true
    )
LIMIT 100
```

which turns out to stop scanning the table once it finds 100 results that match.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from person
where person_id not in
   (
    select person_id 
    from helmet
    where is_safe = false
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT p.*
  FROM Person p
  INNER JOIN Helmet h ON p.id = h.person
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING SUM(h.is_safe) = 0
) inner_select
LIMIT 100
```

So, this query consists of two parts:

1. The workhorse of the query is the inner query. This query joins together each person with all his helmets. It then uses `GROUP BY` two relate all rows for a specific person together. Once we have a group, we can use aggregate functions on each group, and in this case we use `SUM` to count the number of helmets that are safe. The `SUM` is used by the `HAVING`-clause to only select groups that have the SUM of safe helmets (i.e the number of safe helmets) equal to zero.
2. The outer query ensures that the `LIMIT` is applied to the result of the inner query, and not the rows of the tables needed to calculate an accurate result.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you explain how this works (especially the wrapper `SELECT` that's around the rest)?

Comment: Isn't it true that this query's inner query would use the entire table, even though the outer will limit it to 100? The limit of 100 is for performance because there are millions of rows in the `Person` table. If my assumption is true, is there any possible way to have it stop when it finds 100 matching rows? I think I understand that you can't simply apply a `LIMIT` to the inner query, or else once the first 100 rows are processed, the query will never return a match again, right? Is there a way around that, or is that even correct?

Comment: There are ways around it, but I'm no expert in query optimization.. You should really look at @Quassnoi for help, since this is probably very easy for him =) You can also find his blog here, full of good stuff: http://explainextended.com/

Comment: Btw, when I tried this I got an error: `subquery in FROM must have an alias at character 20 - HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
` from Postgres

Comment: Perhaps it's because INNER is a reserved word. Try re-naming `inner` to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person.*
FROM person
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM helmet) AS T2 ON person.id = T2.person_id
WHERE T2.person_id IS NULL
LIMIT 100
```